# microcontrollers and file IO

Tags: c, file, file-io, io, microcontroller

I'm programming a 8051 microcontroller system (in C) connected to a PC via a serial port. I'd like for the µC to write to a file on the PC. Is there a simple general way to do this from the C level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of a off-the-shelf way to do this, but it's not hard to develop yourself.  You will need to:

- Define a serial protocol for transmitting the file data.  There are existing protocols from the old dialup modem days, but they might be too complex.  See:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_transfer_protocols
- Write your microcontroller code to transmit the file data over the serial port, using your protocol.
- Write a program that runs on your PC to receive the data and write it to a file.

Comment: I'd recommend the 1-wire protocol, or even a simplistic version of your own using manchester encoding: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manchester_code

Comment: Telnet is an existing Windows utility that will receive serial data into a file.

Comment: @dave:  do you have a link or reference?  Thanks.

Comment: @earlz:  he says he's already got a serial connection between the PC and microcontroller.

Comment: @payne ah, I misunderstood. It should be almost trivial then to write a quick program in your favorite scripting language(Ruby, Python, Perl, etc) to receive serial data from the microcontroller and write it to a file

Comment: Here's the instructions on enabling telnet: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Telnet-frequently-asked-questions
If you're comfortable setting baud rate, parity etc, it should be a doddle

Comment: Ooh! Looking at that, it wasn't what I was thinking of, sorry. It should do the job, but I was actually thinking of Hyperterminal:
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/What-happened-to-HyperTerminal
But as you can see there, you'll have to search for a downloadable version.
Sorry about the confusion! It's been a few years since I was doing the very same, so my memory of it is a bit hazy!

Comment: @dave:  thanks for the pointers.  telnet didn't seem to be the right tool, but I was being open minded. :-)